# Intercepting Observable.throw using .catch while doing async operations inside the .catch

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5

I want to change the error I get from sending a HTTP post request by transforming it into another error. Unfortunately, this operation is asynchronous (it does some translations). I can't seem to get it to rethrow the `newError` from inside catch callback. Any help?

See example below:

```
public createShorty(shorty: Shorty): Observable<Shorty> {
  const shortyEndpoint = environment.shortyEndpoint;
  const url = `${shortyEndpoint}/shorties`;
  return this.http.post<Shorty>(url, shorty).catch(err => {
    this.errorHandler.transform(err).subscribe(newErr => {
      Observable.throw(newErr);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to transform the error to another object you can't do it inside `subscribe` because you want the new error to be passed down the chain.

Instead inside `catch` run `this.errorHandler.transform` and turn its result into an `error` notification:

```
return this.http.post<Shorty>(url, shorty)
  .catch(err => this.errorHandler.transform(err) // I'm assuming this returns an Observable
    .map(newError => {
      throw newError; // Rethrow the error so it'll be passed down as an `error` notification.
    })
  );
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be what I want. But now the caller of the `createShorty` method is complaining that `_subscribe is not a function`.

Comment: Are you sure `this.errorHandler.transform(err)` returns an Observable?

Comment: Aha, the thing was: I was returning an observable by doing `Observable.create(newError)`. Changed that to `Observable.of(newError)` and it worked. Thanks a bunch!